# geom_sf ignores fill variable when plotting a shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a shapefile using `geom_sf` and to fill the polygons that are plotted with a certain colour. Below, I download the data and plot it, attempting to colour the outlines in red and fill in black.

```r
# Download data
download.file("http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_coastline.zip", 
              destfile = 'coastlines.zip')

# Unzip
unzip(zipfile = "coastlines.zip", 
      exdir = 'ne-coastlines-10m')

# Load packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(ggplot2)

# Load shape file
shp <- read_sf("ne-coastlines-10m/ne_10m_coastline.shp")

# Plot map
ggplot(shp) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "black", colour = "red") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The outline of the geometry is plotted correctly (i.e., in red), but there is no fill. Documentation ([e.g.](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html)) shows fill being used by `geom_sf`, so it's unclear to me why the polygons are not filled in my example. Any ideas?

Comment: As an alternative `ggplot2`, you might want to try the `tmap`-package.

Comment: The polygons are actually the coastline, i.e. the very slim areas along the coasts. Looking at `shp` shows `geometry type:  LINESTRING`

Comment: Do you have to use the coastlines file for any reason? Or can you download a file of land areas instead?

Comment: The shape file you are downloading is has a geometry_type:LINESTRING. I tried polygonize (`shp_polygons <- st_polygonize(shp)`) the lines but the resultt is far from what you expect. You need to find another file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, I guess I'll try and track down another shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

> Below, I download the data and plot it, attempting to colour the outlines in red and fill in black.

> The outline of the geometry is plotted correctly (i.e., in red), but there is no fill.

A solution is to combine the outputs from both countries and coastlines datasets from natural earth:

```
# Download data
download.file("http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_coastline.zip", 
              destfile = 'coastlines.zip')

download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip", 
              destfile = 'countries.zip')

# Unzip
unzip(zipfile = "coastlines.zip", 
      exdir = 'ne-coastlines-10m')

unzip(zipfile = "countries.zip", 
      exdir = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries')

# Load packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Load shape file
shp_coastline <- read_sf("ne-coastlines-10m/ne_10m_coastline.shp")
shp_countries <- read_sf("ne_10m_admin_0_countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")

# Plot map
ggplot(shp) + 
  geom_sf(data=shp_countries, fill = "black", color="black") + 
  geom_sf(data=shp_coastline, colour = "red") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Which gives this:

[image]

If you're using the natural earth datasets frequently, `library(rnaturalearth)` is a good option to extract the sf files directly:

```
# Load packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Load shape file
shp_coastline <- ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") 
shp_countries <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") 

# Plot map
ggplot(shp) + 
  geom_sf(data=shp_countries, fill = "black", color="black") + 
  geom_sf(data=shp_coastline, colour = "red") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```